# Python - Recuperar informações do BD pelo nome das Colunas

Tags: python, select, tabela-banco-de-dados, pyodbc

Caros,
Como recuperar informações do banco de dados pelo nomes das colunas e não pelo índices?

```py
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM [AutomacaoCampanhasDashboard].[dbo].[TBL_GCCP2]')
row = cursor.fetchall()
nome = row[0][1]
endereco = row[1][2]

print(nome)
print(endereco)
```

Gostaria de recuperar as informações dessa forma:

```py
nome = row[Nome]
endereco = row[endereco]

print(nome)
print(endereco)
```

Comment: Pensando em ajudar a galera que está usando mysql, isso só funciona se:
crs = conn.cursor(named_tuple=True) Ref.: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursornamedtuple.html

Answer (score 1):

descobri... bem simples...
Só colocar . (ponto) e o nome da coluna.

`print(row.RESPONSAVEL_TELEFONICA_RA, row.SEGMENTO, row.BENEFICIO_FUTURO)`